# Associativity of concatenation-reduction

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I want to show that concatentation-reduction is associative over an alphabet of two letters $a$ and $b$ and their inverses $a^{-1}$ and $b^{-1}$, concatenate in this sense meaning adding the two words together to make one word, and reduction meaning that any combination of a letter next to its inverse will cancel to the empty word. I don't know how to account for possible reductions when I concatenate any two words in my proof. Would I have to break this up into cases?

Comment: Do you know Newman's diamond lemma?

Comment: No, I haven't heard of it. I figure this proof is possible using only the group axioms and the definition of associativity for a binary operation, but it seems extremely tedious if possible at all.

Comment: Actually, you'll probably need some sort of the lemma to prove that concatenation-reduction is a well-defined operation :)

Comment: But associativity is not hard to prove. Let $\overset{*}{\to}$ be the binary relation on words defined by $\left(u\overset{*}{\to}v\right) \iff \left(\text{$v$ can be obtained from $u$ by some sequence of reduction steps}\right)$. This relation is transitive and reflexive. Prove the **compositionality lemma**: If $u, v, w$ are words satisfying $u \overset{*}{\to} v$, then $wu \overset{*}{\to} wv$ and $uw \overset{*}{\to} vw$. Now, let $\#$ be the "concatenation-reduction" product; thus, $xy \overset{*}{\to} x\# y$ for any words $x, y$. Then, for any three words $u, v, w$, we ...

Comment: ... have $uvw = \left(uv\right) w \overset{*}{\to} \left(u\# v\right) w \overset{*}{\to} \left(u\# v\right) \# w$ and $uvw = u \left(vw\right) \overset{*}{\to} u \left(v\# w\right) \overset{*}{\to} u \# \left(v\# w\right)$. But since any word has a unique reduction (this is where Newman's lemma is used), this yields $\left(u\# v\right) \# w = u \# \left(v\# w\right)$.

Comment: Okay, I see that argument. Is there some way to show that each word has a unique reduction without invoking Newman's lemma?

Comment: Most likely (see the treatment of free groups in some textbooks). Probably by induction on the length on the word.

Comment: You can use van der Waerden's trick: let $F$ be the set of all reduced words; for each $x\in\{a,b,a^{-1},b^{-1}\}$ define the map from $F$ to itself by sending $1$ to $x$, and sending an element of $F$ to the result of concatenating-and-cancelling $x$ on the left. Each of these maps is bijective (with inverse given by $x^{-1}$), and so is a permutation on $F$. Let $G$ be the subgroup of the permutation group $S(F)$ generated by these maps. Define a bijection from $F$ so $S(F)$ in the obvious way, and show that the map respects multiplication. By transport of structure, you get associativity.